# Default initialization in constexpr with std::allocator

Tags: c++, c++20

First I implemented a `constexpr`-capable pseudo-container using naked `new`/`delete`. Then I refactored it to use `std::allocator` for all its goodness. In doing this, I discovered that there's no way to implement a `constexpr` [`uninitialized_default_construct`](https://wg21.link/uninitialized.construct.default), because you can't use placement `new` in `constexpr`, nor is there anything in the C++20 standard with equivalent effects that's also `constexpr`.

Is there no way around this, without heavy changes to implementations of containers to support default initialization in `constexpr`? Other than writing a paper to make `uninitialized_default_construct` `constexpr` or to introduce something like `default_construct_at` akin to [`construct_at`](https://wg21.link/specialized.construct)?

Answer (score 0):

Use naked `new` if you want default initialization in `constexpr` and your container is fixed-size. This means using `delete[]` rather than `std::allocator.deallocate` followed by `std::destroy`. You can still split allocation and construction, but beware to initialize all elements before construction finishes to avoid `delete[]` from attempting to destroy an object in uninitialized memory.

For non-fixed-size containers, support from `std` would be necessary, as called out in the question.

Comment: While my question specifically mentions `std::allocator`, I wonder this answer is good enough if I want to support *Cpp17Allocator*s. It seems like with `std::allocator_traits` as-is, *Cpp17Allocator*s can either support value initialization or default initialization. Some indirection like `uses_allocator` machinery would be needed to support both without changes to `std`.

Comment: Just submitted GCC bug [95797](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95797), because I don't think this should work without replacing all `std::allocator.deallocate()`s and accompanying `std::destroy`s with `delete []`.

Comment: The above has a problem in that you can't support room for growing the container because `delete []` would attempt to delete objects in uninitialized memory. That's not a general solution. Looks like writing a paper as suggested in the question is the only way to go.